# Credit for co-first authorship in Chinese academia

Tags: publications, authorship, china, bioinformatics

I heard that in Chinese academia, you would not get credit for a co-first-author paper if you are not listed as the first co-first author. Is this true? If so, why non-first co-first authors can't get credit for their equal contribution? The area is bioinformatics / computational biology.

Comment: Credit from whom, exactly?

Comment: @Buffy https://www.science.org/content/article/cash-bonuses-peer-reviewed-papers-go-global and https://www.enago.com/academy/paid-to-publish-the-chinese-cash-cow/ 
add imprecations of your choice

Comment: @Buffy. Credit that I meant was whether the universities would consider co-authored papers as my work if I am not the first co-first author when applying for a position in Chinese academia. Is a non-first co-first-authored (or sole first author) paper considered my first-author paper? Or is it not different from a second-author paper?